# FosUserBundle: password reset request link is sent instead of resetting link

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to send email with password reset link. This is my method:

```
 public function sendPasswordResettingEmail(User $user){

    $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_resetting_reset',
        array('token' => $user->getConfirmationToken()), UrlGenerator::ABSOLUTE_URL);

    $html = $this->templating->render('CoreBundle:Email:password_reset.email.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
        'confirmationUrl' =>  $url
    ));

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setContentType('text/html')
            ->setSubject('Password reset')
            ->setFrom(array(self::EMAIL_FROM => 'App'))
            ->setTo($user->getEmail())
            ->setBody($html);

    $this->service->get('mailer')->send($message);
}
```

But I get email with

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/resetting/request
```

link, which takes me to a form asking for email or username. I need to submit my email address again to get resetting

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/resetting/reset
```

link.

Is it possible to get `reset` link and skip `request` step? because I am already providing user parameter to method.